# No locked off youth gearing restriction for road racing British National Series/Championships

Tags: gears, racing, uk

Can anyone correctly confirm (by providing a link to the exact rule in British Cycling rulebook), if the use of locked off gears is permitted in Youth (A, B and Junior) National level series or championship road races? We have had experience of different rulings this year, 2017.

I cannot find any reference to this rule on the British Cycling website, but have found reference to it on a forum that didn't specify any country, and also a page on US Youth Cycling.

UPDATE: Further advice/comment we have received is that there is a International/UCI (race) ruling stating that youth (A, B, Junior) level are not permitted to use locked off gears, and that the full range of cassette/rings must be within the limitations of that category. Whether British National Series events are included within this appears to be on a race by race basis - and the best advice I can give anyone reading this post is to (a) check well in advance of any race what the ruling is to be applied on the day and (b) you may as well go out and buy from the start the correct limited gears.

UPDATE 2023: As of 2023, gears restrictions have been removed for all Junior racing (UCI ruling and implemented by national bodies). Youth gear restrictions still apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A year and a bit on, I'd like to answer my own question. In the UK, I've not seen anyone turned away from National Championship races for having locked off gears, and the ruling that was sent to us, wasn't necessarily implemented at the event we attended.

However, if you are going to race in continental Europe (such as Assen Youth Tour, or any other race for that matter), then you have to ride on a specific chainring and 10 or 11 speed cassette for your category with full range, and this therefore, is not locked off. We therefore had to switch to this format for all our bikes (spare wheels as well, of course), and thus you negate the whole need to lock gears off. As I stated in my original question, the best advice is to fit the bike from the start with the appropriate cassette (you'll have to dig around to source them).

Answer (score 3):

[The British Cycling Technical Regulations](https://www.britishcycling.org.uk/zuvvi/media/bc_files/rulebook/2017/C7_-_Technical_Regulations_For_General_Road_Track_and_Roller_Racing.pdf) make no mention of limiting in section 3.3 Gear Restrictions.

However BC themselves give instructions on using the limit screws in [this explanatory leaflet](https://www.britishcycling.org.uk/zuvvi/media/bc_files/volunteer/Youth_Gear_Restrictions_for_Riders.Parents.pdf).

I suspect it's up to your charm and the mood of the commissaire.

Comment: Maybe a nice colour printout of both to wave around would help?

Comment: Many thanks for the responses - please note my EDIT of original posting

Comment: @Phil For your future reference, on SE its acceptable to answer your own questions. Your edit could have been put up as an answer.

Comment: @Mattnz thanks for the guidance - Im going to put up a fully answer iun the hope it helps someone